# Upload an image to Wordpress from URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a user-submitted post tool for a Wordpress site.

The user can enter an image URL and I want it to be added to the post along with other content like title and post content.

I've got this working using a regular image attachment. I create the post and then attach the image using this script:

```
 $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];

 $file = array(
    'name' => $files['name'],
    'type' => $files['type'],
    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'],
    'error' => $files['error'],
    'size' => $files['size']
);

$_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
     $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$userPost);
    }
```

But how can I do the same thing using `insert_attachment()` or similar but with a URL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003996/how-can-i-upload-an-image-from-a-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). You'd probably have to do something like this:

```
file_put_contents('your_file_on_server.xxx', file_get_contents('http://someurl.com/filename.xxx'));
```

This would download the file from the specified url and save it to your server. From there you can slightly modify your original code to attach it to a post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've successfully copied the file to my server but I'm not sure how to do the second part: modifying the code to treat a URL as it would $_FILES. I'd love something like `$file = get_file($image_url)`. Then I could access its attributes like `$file['name']`.

Comment: Actually there's such a function. Check out [fileinfo_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). If you're using PHP >= 5.3, it's already available. If not, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) out and follow the install instructions.